# ChartJS donut chart clipping the edges

Tags: reactjs, canvas, chart.js

I have a widget that displays a donut chart for revenue data. The problem I am having is that on two sides, the edges of the donut are cut off. It looks like the chart is overflowing the canvas, but I am not sure why.

Here is the options and data:

```
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function (context) {
            return ` ${context.label}: ${context.formattedValue}%`;
          },
        },
      },
    },
    offset: 12,
    borderRadius: 4,
    elements: {
      arc: {
        borderWidth: 0,
      },
    },
  };

  const data = {
    labels: chartLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: chartData,
        backgroundColor: colors,
      },
    ],
  };
```

In the HTML, this is what is created:

`<canvas role="img" height="360" width="360" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 180px; width: 180px;"></canvas>`

That's what the chart looks like.
[image: Donut Chart]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am hoping you are using it with react

you need to wrap your import inside nested `<div>` and need to add `display: flex` for parent `div` and also need to remove `offset:12`
check following code snippet

```
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <div>
            <Doughnut
              data={data}
              options={{
                plugins: {
                  legend: {
                    display: false,
                  },
                  tooltip: {
                    callbacks: {
                      label: function (context) {
                        return ` ${context.label}: ${context.formattedValue}%`;
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
                borderRadius: 4,
                elements: {
                  arc: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                  },
                },
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I am using this with React.

Removing the offset does solve the problem, but I still need some space between the arcs. Is there a way to do that without the offset?

Comment: I figured out how that I can add a white border to the arc and it will provide the offset without clipping the chart. I also added `hoverBorderColor` and set it to white so it wouldn't show when you hover.

https://i.imgur.com/xzIeWWQ.png

Comment: you have option for that CUTOUT `options={{ cutout: [100, 95, 90], layout: { padding: 1 } }}`